# `react-native-camera` returns a data.uri but image cannot be accessed (no such file or directory)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera

I would appreciate any help on this.
I'm using **[react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RNCamera.md)** and when I get the URI of the image taken using `takePictureAsync(`) method, I can't access that image.

I took the photo and navigate to the next screen, passing the image data as the params:

```
  const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
  console.log(data);
  this.props.navigation.navigate('FFV', {
    postItem: data.uri
  });
```

In the next screen (FFV) I am loading the photo into `<Image/>` ,it works if I pass the **base64** of the image, but doesn't work if I just pass the **URI**.

```
<Image style={styles.imagePreview}
          source={{ isStatic:true, uri: postItem }}
          resizeMode="contain"
 />
```

The image doesn't render and if I try to save the file using CameraRoll, I get "No such file or directory".

[image: First the image data is printed out, second is the error accessing the file]

I've tested on the emulator and on physical device - same problem.
It doesn't seem to be related to `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, because after I granted the permissions, the `ENOENT` error occurs.

I check the cache of the app on the phone, and it doesn't have those files, does it mean it's not writing it? If there were issues with the RNCamera I would think the URI wouldn't be returned successfully.

```
"react-native": "0.57.1",
"react-native-camera": "^1.3.0",
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: try the uri without "file:///"

Comment: @Kranthi tried it, didn't help. I also tried with and w/o extension ".jpg" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and end up by using this `CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri)`.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I'd love to know if anyone has come up with a way around this without saving to the camera roll. I'd like to avoid filling up the user's camera roll if possible.

Comment: @MurphyRandle did you get anything?

Comment: @JustABeginner I wish I remembered! But I think I was able to use expo-camera ('cause I was using Expo), get the temp URI they return after taking a picture, copy the image to a permanent location using the file APIs, and then I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove any `file://` prefix of the file, e.g.:

```
    const uri = data.uri.startsWith('file://')
              ? data.uri.substr('file://'.length)
              : data.uri;
```

Comment: Got the error: Error: Source file not found.
    at fs.js:283